# Matlab loading large dataset returns 0

Tags: mysql, matlab, large-data

I am trying to load a simple, but fairly large table from a MySQL database into Matlab (the table is about 16'000'000 x 18)

The MySQL database size is 2.6 GB, and my Windows machine has 32 GB of memory, so in principle, memory should not be a problem.

I tried to load the data via a simple fetch:

```
curs = exec(conn,['SELECT * FROM mydb.large_table']);
curs = fetch(curs);
data = curs.Data;
```

I also tried to use the select function, but in both instances `data` is simply returned as 0.

As there are no error messages, and as it does not seem that I am even close to any matlab or memory size restrictions, I am at a loss to understand what is going wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[added : ]

Did some further checks:

- Tried to pre-allocate memory for the table, pulling in the first row of the table and then replicating it 20 million time. No problem there.
- Was able to pull in 2.5m rows. 6m failed again
- Watching the memory consumption (Windows Task Manager), I noticed that onces the exec statement pulled all the data from the database onto the local machine, the fetch command started to eat up memory. For 6m rows, the memory in use first increased to the full available 32 GB, then dropped to 2GB (where it stayed), but the Committed memory went up a staggering 125 GB !

I have absolutely no idea what is going on here

Comment: I would try to increase that restriction until I hit the point where it no longer works, to figure out where that limit is. It is possible that some bit of code somewhere along the way has a 31-bit limit to some value. I've seen plenty of C and C++ code using `int` for size. `int` is a 32-bit signed value. Thus, such code usually cannot deal with data past 2 Gb (sometimes the limit is 2 G elements, but you get the issue).

Comment: Followed your suggestion. See above the added comment.

Comment: that was an interesting experiment, thanks for doing that. I honestly think that this is a bug. This is something you should [report to the Mathworks](https://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us.html). In terms of solving your immediate problem, can you read the table in blocks? If you can read 2m rows, maybe you can read the next 2m separately?

Comment: What is the datatype of the values in the DB? What is the datatype after you import it? Is imported table itself a `table`, a `cell`, a numeric array or anything else? I'm thinking MATLAB loads the data into some buffer as `double`, then tries to figure out if it can convert it to something more memory-friendly, but intermediately there are more arrays being created... I'd go with the "load in chunks" suggestion. Perhaps even `tall` arrays.

Comment: The data is loaded into a data table, as the underlying database table has a mixture of string and numeric data.